# Give an dynamically created element an id

Tags: javascript, html

I have created a posting system in js and for the element I create within the unordered list I want to assign it an id (e.g `<p id="Hello">...</p>`). Using the posting system (in js) the newly created html element shall be given an id.

js code:

```
function publish() {
    var title = document.getElementById("title").value;
    var description = document.getElementById("description").value;
    var para = document.createElement("h3");
    var node = document.createTextNode(title);
    para.appendChild(node);

    var element = document.getElementById("posts");
    element.appendChild(para);

    var para = document.createElement("small");
    var node = document.createTextNode("--".concat(description, "--"));
    para.appendChild(node);

    var image = document.getElementById("posts");
    element.appendChild(para)
    var image = document.createElement("img");
    var imageInput = document.getElementById('image-file');
    image.src = URL.createObjectURL(imageInput.files[0]);
    image.style.height = '100px';
    image.style.width = '100px';

    para.appendChild(image);
}
```

html code:

```
    <button id="publish-button" onclick="publish();">Publish</button>
        <p>Title</p>
        <input class="Title" id="title"></input>

        <p>Description</p>
        <input class="Description" id="description"></input>

        <p>Images</p>
        <input id="image-file" type="file" />
<ul id="posts">
    </ul>
```

Comment: so u wanto assign those random IDs in js or HTML or what? vague;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This adds id='1' to the small tag and will increment by 1 each time you add an image.  Just declare a global for id and then set para.id = id

```js
var id=0;
function publish() {
    var title = document.getElementById("title").value;
    var description = document.getElementById("description").value;
    var para = document.createElement("h3");
    var node = document.createTextNode(title);
    para.appendChild(node);

    var element = document.getElementById("posts");
    element.appendChild(para);

    var para = document.createElement("small");
    id++;
    para.id=id;
    var node = document.createTextNode("--".concat(description, "--"));
    para.appendChild(node);

    var image = document.getElementById("posts");
    element.appendChild(para)
    var image = document.createElement("img");
    var imageInput = document.getElementById('image-file');
    image.src = URL.createObjectURL(imageInput.files[0]);
    image.style.height = '100px';
    image.style.width = '100px';

    para.appendChild(image);
}
```

```html
<button id="publish-button" onclick="publish();">Publish</button>
        <p>Title</p>
        <input class="Title" id="title"></input>

        <p>Description</p>
        <input class="Description" id="description"></input>

        <p>Images</p>
        <input id="image-file" type="file" />
<ul id="posts">
    </ul>
```